# Nagios Admin User account

Tags: apache-http-server, monitoring, nagios

I would like to know my nagiosadmin password.
I have already forgotton my password but i am the root user of my ubuntu os.
Is it safe to sudo htpasswd /etc/nagios3/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin and key in a new password ?

Will my other user accounts be affected?
Restart of apache and nagios is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make backup of the file and go to change it

And yes, you need to restart nagios to get new password in charge

Comment: thank you. if it goes well my reset of my password. my settings and the configurations i have set up in the past will still remain?

Comment: Yes, of course. This action will change only the password of this particular user